# Apache Ignite Server Node(2.9.1) with Persistence Enabled using Java 15 throwing Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ignite, gridgain

**Exception:**

```
[15:30:27,658][SEVERE][main][IgniteKernal] Exception during start processors, node will be stopped and close connections
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Object, Object[])" because "org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.filehandle.FileWriteHandleImpl.mappingOffset" is null
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.filehandle.FileWriteHandleImpl.fsync(FileWriteHandleImpl.java:450)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.filehandle.FileWriteHandleImpl.fsync(FileWriteHandleImpl.java:419)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.filehandle.FileHandleManagerImpl.flush(FileHandleManagerImpl.java:270)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager.flush(FileWriteAheadLogManager.java:905)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.tailPointer(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:2159)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.startMemoryRestore(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:2087)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1257)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2052)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1698)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1114)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:634)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:560)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:328)
```

**Ignite Configuration :**

```
  public static IgniteConfiguration createConfiguration() {
    
    IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

    // Enabling peer-class loading feature.
    cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);

    DataStorageConfiguration dataStorageCfg = new DataStorageConfiguration();
    // Setting Persistence Enabled true
    dataStorageCfg.getDefaultDataRegionConfiguration().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    cfg.setDataStorageConfiguration(dataStorageCfg);
    
    return cfg;
    
  }
```

**Although same configuration with Java 8 & 11 is working fine.**

Also there is no issue with **PersistenceEnabled(false)** in Java 15

Answer (score 3):

Ignite is only really tested with the LTS versions of Java, i.e., Java 8 and 11. I would stick with those versions.

Update: Apache Ignite 2.13 supports Java 17.

Answer (score 0):

Try using following VM arguments, mentioned here:
 https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start/java#running-ignite-with-java-11

> ```
> --add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
> --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
> --add-exports=java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver=ALL-UNNAMED
> --add-exports=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED
> --add-exports=java.base/sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects=ALL-UNNAMED
> --add-opens=jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED
> --illegal-access=permit
> ```